# selenium in python : Return the special value

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

I want to get the number 31 in the shaded blue block here. So, I typed code.

```
val=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]")
print(val)
```

(The xpath of the box marked 31 is `/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]`.)

But, I get

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3e74d73f7dc4cd9a52b5430b7fa69678", element="0.771890890368685-1")>
```

What should I do to get the number 31? ^^

Comment: Could you supply raw version of html file for testing?

Comment: This page is only visible when I log in with my personal ID. I am curious to know the value in the box. when I know the xpath of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the entire element.  An element is a complex object with a lot of attributes and such.  But you really only want the **text** of the element.

So use:

`print(val.text)`